# Calculating time difference in sound input from multiple microphones

Tags: c#, input, time, microphone

I have a C# project that takes multiple (2 at the moment) microphones as an audio devices, detects sound from them, processes their audio frames with Fourier Transform and displays them. It also prints them in three colors: red is for microphone that has stronger input, green is for microphone that has weaker input and grey is for frames that arent strong enough to be of any interest.

Next step of my project is to calculate the time difference of sound samples that arrive at each microphone. For example if i speak directly to one microphone and the other is 3 feet away, the difference should be about 3 ms (assuming sound speed at 1feet/ms). This is of course just an example.

Can anyone help me with this? I've made my project based on this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20025/Sound-visualizer-in-C

Comment: in my experience, microphone input is received in packets at regular intervals, so relying on the time they were received probably won't work. You could perhaps try comparing each received packet from the 2 microphones and try and determine the offset.

Comment: I have actually found a decent solution to my problem here - http://www.laurentcalmes.lu/soundloc_software.html It has two algorithms in MatLab that just need adjusting to my C# code. These look promising, so I'll try to implement them and let know if it works. Thank you for answering, Steven.